# How can I add a field in a model in odoo 9 new API?

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I am trying to add a new field in the model of SaleOrderLine (Official Sale module).

It works perfect with the old API:

```
from openerp import _
from openerp.osv import osv, fields

class SaleOrderLineExt(osv.osv):
    _inherit = ['sale.order.line']

    _columns = {
        'my_field_code': fields.float(string='My field Code'),
    }
```

But, If I try to use the new API, the field is not created in the database.

```
from openerp import api, fields, models, _

class SaleOrderLineExt(models.Model):
    _inherit = ['sale.order.line']

    my_field_code = fields.Float(string='My field Code'),
```

I have read the [Odoo new API guideline](http://odoo-new-api-guide-line.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fields.html) and it appears that my code is right, but it is not working.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Remove the `,` at the end of the `my_field_code` line

Comment: @CarlosMayo thanks. That's it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with following code.

```
from openerp import api, fields, models, _

class SaleOrderLineExt(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order.line'

    my_field_code = fields.Float(string='My field Code')
```

Remove `,` at the end of field declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Just Remove the semicolon which is at the end of field. You code will definitely work.